# Deploying solution from Dev to Production fails because column with same schema name data type was changed. Object dependencies won't get deleted

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

So the column in question was a lookup column, which i deleted in the unmanaged solution, and mistakenly created a new column with the same name. Dynamics by default will use the same auto-generated schema name based on the display name. So when I go to import the unmanaged solution in my dev environment into the production environment as managed, obviously it throws an error because of the mismatched of data types per column schema name.

[Error returned by Azure Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbV4E.png)

So I did the sensible next thing, and went to delete this column in my dev environment. But oh no! There are object dependencies which prevent me from deleting it, okay I look at which objects depend on this column, it is a form, i remove the column from the form, go to delete and oh no again! There is still a dependency on the form I just deleted the column from.

So what do I do? I can't change the column schema name, I can't change the data type back to the data type that's currently in the managed solution. Is this when I open up a microsoft support ticket? Hopefully someone here has some insight. Thanks!

Comment: Publish the form. Then the dependency should disappear. In the end it must be possible to remove all dependencies.

Comment: I've published the form with the column removed multiple times, opened the form online and made sure it was gone but the solution manager still said the form was using it.

Comment: Create a solution with this form only. Export the solution as unmanaged. Extract the customization.xml from the zip. Edit the xml and remove all references to your attribute. Paste the customization.xml into the zip and import and publish the solution.

Comment: Okay so the only way I found out how to get the form id so i could find the attribute in the large xml file was to create a javascript function that printed the forms id using console.log.

Is there a better/easier way to get a forms id without using a script?

-- Edit, just read your comment carefully. If I create a solution with this form only, how will this show that the form is removed in my environments solution?

Comment: @CarlSagan You can get form id from the URL when you are editing the form.

Comment: @CarlSagan: why would you need to remove the form? My understanding was that the form still holds a dependency to the column. In that case you just need to add the form to a solution, export the solution and edit the form XML by hand. You do not need the form id per se, however it can be found in the page url when editing the form.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen Sorry that last reply wasn't clear. So the steps would be.
1. Create solution, add form to solution
2. Remove references to that column in the xml
3. Re-import solution into environment
4. Add the form as a component in my original solution?

I don't need to remove the form. The column I want to remove from the form was being used with a custom control. This custom control is not on the forms UI, but is still in the forms xml. I'm thinking I can just delete this control from the xml and reimport?

Didn't know that about the formid in the page url, thanks!

Comment: @CarlSagan: yes, the procedure you summarized is correct. However, I think you could as well try removing the custom control using the classic form designer. It should be visible of one of the field property tabs.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen well i ended up opening a microsoft support ticket just to be safe and the guy decided to run a custom script without testing or asking me if it was okay first. So let's see how this goes haha.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen I would mark this comment chain as the answer if I could.

Comment: @CarlSagan: I converted my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute can be associated with a custom control. Try removing this custom control using the classic form designer. It should be visible on one of the field property tabs.

If the attribute cannot be found anywhere on the form using the classic or modern form designer, try this:

Create a solution with this form only. Export the solution as unmanaged. Extract the customization.xml from the zip. Edit the xml and remove all references to your attribute. Paste the customization.xml into the zip and import and publish the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to delete a managed component is to upgrade the solution. In your case, you can delete the field and dependency in solution and apply the upgrade to target environment. **Please noticed that all data in this field would get deleted when you apply the upgrade.** [You may check this link for more detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/update-solutions)

Comment: I wouldn't have a problem deleting the field since there has been no data associated with it in the managed solution. I'd still prefer to figure out why the dependency checker is not working properly.

Question about upgrading a managed solution, I've done this before and it seemed to have deleted my solutions permissions and roles assigned to the users and reset the records associated with them. Any insights?

Comment: Oh yeah, the problem is I can't delete the field and dependency.

Comment: @CarlSagan You may try to publish all customizations in default solution and remove field from all forms and publish all customizations, after this you should be able to delete the field.

Comment: I'm a little bit inexperienced when it comes to solution management. Why would the default solution have anything to do with the solution that has all the custom components for my dynamics instance?

Comment: I think it is by design. If there is no default solution, then it will be hard to find some components.